# ASP.NET C# Login unexpected results from sqlexpress database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Let me Preface this with I am a student, this is a project for a class and i've roughly translated the coding from my professors Visual Basic into C#, my code from my code behind is below.

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conUser = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["COP2823ConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmdUser = new SqlCommand();
        string strSQL;
        SqlDataReader dtrUser;
        DateTime timestamp = new DateTime();

        strSQL = "select * FROM students WHERE studentid=@studentid AND courseid=@courseid AND password=@pwd";
        cmdUser.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmdUser.CommandText = strSQL;
        cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@studentid", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Login1.UserName;
        cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@courseid", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "COP2823";
        cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@pwd", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Login1.Password;

        conUser.Open();
        cmdUser.Connection = conUser;
        dtrUser = cmdUser.ExecuteReader();
        if (dtrUser.HasRows)
        {
            dtrUser.Read();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["sid"] = dtrUser["studentid"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["fname"] = dtrUser["first"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["lname"] = dtrUser["last"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ulevel"] = dtrUser["userlevel"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["email"] = dtrUser["email"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["course"] = "COP2823";

            dtrUser.Close();
            conUser.Close();

            strSQL = "UPDATE students SET lastlogin=@lastlogin WHERE studentid=@user2";
            cmdUser.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmdUser.CommandText = strSQL;
            timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@user2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Login1.UserName;
            cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@lastlogin", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = timestamp.ToString();

            conUser.Open();
            cmdUser.Connection = conUser;
            dtrUser = cmdUser.ExecuteReader();
            dtrUser.Close();
            conUser.Close();
        }
        dtrUser.Close();
        conUser.Close();
    }

 protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login1_Authenticate(null, null);
    }
```

Now the issue i'm having is when I use the login feature I can literally type anything I want and it grants me access, if I press the actual login button it says failed login. My assumption is it has to do with my

```
cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@studentid", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Login1.UserName;
cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@courseid", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "COP2823";
cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@pwd", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Login1.Password;
```

but I haven't been able to find the proper usage. I apologize if this is a repeat question, i've already worked out alot of other issues pertaining to the database, I have a comment section that uses the database and works just fine, a gridview that access the database fine.

Comment: You **definitely** should learn how to debug the code! This way you don't only presume what happens but you actually track it, line by line. Thus, you can test both flows, the correct and incorrect credentials and see what happens, what data the database returns etc. My assumption is that although the success path seem to put something into the `Session` container, you don't make any use of it anywhere.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I did use the symbolic debugger with correct credentials and it shows my information, first name last name etc, I did not try it with incorrect credentials. I was using the session container and it was working fine, until I realized that i was getting by with pressing Enter and not the login button.

Comment: It's really really bad to compare passwords directly like this. The password in the database should be a cryptographic hash of the original. When someone tries to login, you use the same hashing scheme on the attempted password, and compare the hashes. Anything else will eventually get you hacked and leak data. This is one of those few things that's too important to even do wrong in learning code.

Answer (score 1):

when entering login page, sessions should be cleared, it might that after first successful attempt of logging in, sessions still hold values, hence correct authentication.

```cs
//here in login page
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     HttpContext.Current.Session["studentid"] = null;
//repeat code for other sessions

    }
```

this is the proper usage for adding parameter values to cmd command

```cs
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", value);
```

about being able to login even if the credentials are incorrect:

you are assigning sessions, when you redirect to the wanted page, are you checking 
if the sessions are loaded?. like this:

```cs
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["studentid"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

if not nothing will make the webpage block you from accessing it

Comment: I did, I did                                                                                                                  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["ulevel"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
    }

Comment: i'll have to check my session variables on my other pages and try to attack it from that point.

Comment: when you enter the login, you should at first clear the sessions, set them to null, because it could be that from the first attempt, you are entering correct credentials, and then sessions are being filled, after relogging, sessions are still filled. so the other page doesn't kick out. if this doesn't work you should  debug the program, follow and watch what is the result of the command and what are the values of the sessions each time

Comment: There are problems with the `AddWithValue()` method. What the OP is doing to use `Add()` with an exact type is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but I wanted to help you clean up some things, and the new code includes a couple things that might have been missing to address the question directly.

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string SQL = "
      SELECT * 
      FROM students 
      WHERE studentid=@studentid AND courseid=@courseid AND password=@pwd;
      -- Update login time as part of the SAME SQL BATCH!
      If @@rowcount = 1 BEGIN
          UPDATE students
          SET LastLogin = current_timestamp
          WHERE studentid = @studentid ;
      END";

    // using blocks guarantee the connection is closed, even if an exception is thrown.
    // The original code would have left the connection hanging open if there was an exception.
    using (var conUser = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["COP2823ConnectionString"].ToString()))
    using (var cmdUser = new SqlCommand(SQL, conUser))
    {
        cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@studentid", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Login1.UserName;
        cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@courseid", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "COP2823";
        // Should be using a HASH VALUE here!
        cmdUser.Parameters.Add("@pwd", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CreatePwdHash(Login1.Password);

        conUser.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dtrUser = cmdUser.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dtrUser.Read())          
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["sid"] = dtrUser["studentid"];
                HttpContext.Current.Session["fname"] = dtrUser["first"];
                HttpContext.Current.Session["lname"] = dtrUser["last"];
                HttpContext.Current.Session["ulevel"] = dtrUser["userlevel"];
                HttpContext.Current.Session["email"] = dtrUser["email"];
                HttpContext.Current.Session["course"] = "COP2823";

                if (e is object) e.Authenticated = true;
            }
            else //This section was missing!
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["sid"] = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["fname"] = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["lname"] = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["ulevel"] = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["email"] = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["course"] = null;

                if (e is object) e.Authenticated = false;
            }
            dtrUser.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THIS THIS RIGHT HERE, thank you sir. I had to move a few things around but this solved all of my problems. now i'm going to take your advice on hashing the passwords to avoid hacking. thank you so much